# Highcharts crosshair event

Tags: highcharts

I am using the ["Custom Events" highchart plugin by Black Label](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/15/Custom-Events), to detect right click in my chart. My goal is to use the right click in the chart as "Back" button when drilling out from my custom data. I know highchart has drilling options embedded, but this is a highly custom application, and my problem is that I need a way to detect right click on the [x-axis crosshair line](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.crosshair).Since the crosshair is following the mouse, 90% percent of the right clicks is triggered on the crosshair line itself, and I can not manage to detect that click. I need the event to be catched inside highcharts, because there is multiple charts on my page, and I need to know which chart was clicked on, and on what point.

I hope you understand my explanation and problem.

BR,
Benjamin Kruger

Comment: Do you have a fiddle with your custom set up that we can see?

Comment: Defaulty, the custom-events does not catch the events on the crosshair. But this solution seems to not be very user-friendly. So could you replicate your example as live demo to introduce your goal ?